# It doesn't work on leetcode but it works on vscode -- an array problem

Tags: arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

UPDATE: It doesn't work because I didn't set `returnSize` inside the function and leetcode expects that parameter to have a value as Jerry Jeremiah said in the comments.

Here is the problem: Given the array nums consisting of `2n` elements in the form `[x1,x2,...,xn,y1,y2,...,yn]`.

Return the array in the form `[x1,y1,x2,y2,...,xn,yn]`

```c
int* shuffle(int* nums, int numsSize, int n, int* returnSize) {
    int *answer = (int*) malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int));
    int a,k,i;
    
    for (i = 0, k = n, a = 0; i < numsSize-1; i += 2, k++, a++) {
        answer[i] = nums[a];
        answer[i+1] = nums[k];
    }
    return answer;
}
```

First i thought that i couldn't allocate the memory correctly but i think that's not that.

I've tried several other approaches to the problem but it's all same output i don't know why?

Even though the code is same, my outputs varies for the same test. Some of them are: [], ], [2,1]

I'm not looking for another method to solve the problem. I'm just wondering why i get these outputs in
leetcode but not in my vscode.

Can you guys help me figure out?

Comment: Try stepping through the code in the debugger. Also, please format your code before sharing it with others (and for your own sanity, too, TBH)

Comment: Reformatted as requested.

Comment: You don't set returnSize inside the function and leetcode probably expects that parameter to have a value.

Comment: Ohhh.. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Dankindonut, what did you set returnSize to? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `'\0'` to end of memory might help

```cpp
int* answer=(int*)malloc((numsSize + 1) * sizeof(int))
answer[(numsSize + 1)] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when i tried it, compiler gave heap-buffer-overflow error.

Comment: It is an array of int - not a string of char.

Comment: yeah i got u need to allocate * returnSize = answerSize; int doesn't need '\0'